# why is a new Graphics object not passed to paintComponent method in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, paintcomponent, jcomponent

I am reading `swing tutorial`. From what is mentioned there:

```
The paintComponent method of JComponent is automatically called 
when a frame is drawn/re-drawn.
```

But, what I do not understand is what is the `Graphics Object` that is passed to it. I do not see
any new object of `Graphics` type being `instanstiated` and passed. so how does all this happen?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
              Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
              g2.drawimage(image,x,y,null);
              //
            }
```

I guess it is a similar situation with `actionlisteners`. But in this case, The `actionPerformed` is called automatically when `event` occurs such as `button click` and the events gets passed to the `actionPerformed`. There is no need to separately call this method and pass the `Actionevent object`. But I do not understand how it happens with `paintComponent` method.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
              //do something
     } 
   });
```

Thanks

Comment: See also [*Painting in AWT and Swing*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Graphics` object is created by the paint sub system.

You should never be calling `paintComponent` yourself and should simply allow the paint system deal with it.  Even if you wanted to capture or print the component using your `Graphics` context (from something like BufferedImage), you should be using `print` or `printAll`

Take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: I will read that link, but is that each time `paintComponent` method is called, a new `Graphics` object is created. That would be waste of resources correct?

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't care, but in practice, no.  I believe the `Graphics` object is changed/created when the window is attached to a native peer. Then, basically, all the components share the same `Graphics` context until the window is closed.  This is why you should NEVER call `dispose` on a `Graphcis` context you did not create

Comment: may be not very relevant here, but `repaint()` needs to be explicitly called, whereas `paint()` not. If I have, `paintComponent` how does this work?

Comment: Calling `repaint` puts a `paint` event onto the Event Queue, which is passed to the `RepaintManager` which makes decisions about what and when something should be painted.  `paint` is the action, `repaint` is the request.

Comment: so does the `paintComponent` has any relation to them? The `paintComponent` gets called when Frame is drawn/re-drawn. That means I don't have to `repaint` when I use `paintComponent`?

Comment: so a `repaint()` has be to called explicitly, if I want my frame to be `redrawn`.?

Comment: Sometimes.  Some components are bound, so they provide the container with some idea that something has changed and needs to be revalidated and repainted...

Comment: I have a question that is very similar to this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21106626/how-are-the-appropriate-methods-of-mousemotionlistener-in-java-swing

Answer (score 3):

They are similar issues. The Graphics object is created by the Swing library at the request o the JVM and passed into the `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method when the JVM makes this method call. Because you yourself are not directly calling this method, you never see the object being created.